# Let $S_k= \left( 1 - \frac{1}{k} , 2 + \frac{1}{k} \right],k \geq 1$ find $ \bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty} S_k$ ...

Tags: real-analysis

> Let $S_k= \left( 1 - \frac{1}{k} , 2 + \frac{1}{k} \right],k \geq 1$
>
> find
>
> (a) $ \bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty} S_k $
>
> (b) $ \bigcap_{k=1}^{\infty} S_k $
>
> (c) $ \bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty} S_{k}^{c} $
>
> (d) $ \bigcap_{k=1}^{\infty} S_{k}^{c} $

Given that

$S_1=(0,3]$

$S_2=(0.5,2.5]$

$S_3=( \frac{2}{3} , 2\frac{1}{3}]$

...

(a) It shows that $S_1$ contains $S_k$, $\forall k \geq 1$

It follows that $ \bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty} S_k  = S_1$

(b) $ \bigcap_{k=1}^{\infty} S_k = S_{\infty} $

(c) $ \bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty} S_{k}^{c} = (-\infty, 0] \cup (3, + \infty)$

(d) $ \bigcap_{k=1}^{\infty} S_{k}^{c} = ? $

I am not convinced about my answer (b) and not sure what to deduce to answer (d)

much appreciated

Comment: Re (b), what is $S_\infty$? Unless you explain this (and prove your solution, of course), there is no answer to (b) here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $b)$ you have to show that $\bigcap_{k\geq 1}S_k=S_{\infty}$, but what is $S_{\infty}$? It should be $S_{\infty}=[1,2]$. Naively you could argue that $S_{\infty}$ should be $(1,2]$ but clearly $1\in S_k$ for all $k\geq 1$.

Indeed, we will show that $\cap_{k\geq 1}S_k=[1,2]$. Notice that for any $k\geq 1$ we have that $[1,2]\subset S_k$, hence $[1,2]\subset \bigcap_{k\geq 1}S_k$.

Conversely, take $x\in \bigcap_{k\geq 1}S_k$. Then for any $k\geq 1$ we have that $x> 1-\frac{1}{k}$ and $x\leq 2+\frac{1}{k}$. Thus $x\geq 1$ and $x\leq 2$. It follows that $x\in [1,2]$. This shows the reverse inclusion as well.

You can approach $c)$ in a similar fashion. $d)$ can be solved by using some general principles.